# LaunchAgents zip/tar not working in plist?

Tags: terminal, backup, command-line, bash, launchd

I created the `plist` for a  'custom' backup agent (via LaunchAgent). The (zip) program is called, but I keep getting a 'zip error: Nothing to do!' in my logs.

I assume it has something todo with permissions. I did add `sh` and `zip` to my `Full Disk Access` security settings. But it did not help.

*On a side-note, when I move the zip command in a shell (sh) script, it works.*

I would like to know why using the `zip` command directly doesn't?

Running the command for the terminal works also without issues, like so:

```
/usr/bin/zip /Users/username/Backup/test.zip /Users/username/Documents/*.pdf
```

LaunchAgent script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myuser.DailyBackup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/zip</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/username/Backup/test.zip</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Documents/*.pdf</string> 
    </array>    
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/my.backup.log</string>    
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/my.backup.err</string>    
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>    
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man launchd.plist`

```
ProgramArguments <array of strings>
This key maps to the second argument of execvp(3) and specifies the argument vector to be passed
to the job when a process is spawned. This key is required in the absence of the Program key.
IMPORTANT: Many people are confused by this key. Please read execvp(3) very carefully!
```

So you need to use

```
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/zip</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>zip</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Backup/test.zip</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Documents/*.pdf</string> 
    </array>
```

It still won't work though because `launchd` doesn't expand wildcards and `zip` doesn't either. It's easier to use `launchd` to start a shell script which does all the work then.

Comment: Thanks, zip does accepts wildcards. My command to just zip PDF seems to work fine. Which makes it more strange...

Comment: Running `zip foo '*'` gives a `zip error: Nothing to do!` error so unless you've installed another version of `zip` into `/usr/bin` I doubt that it knows how to expand wildcards.

Comment: Your example of zipping up PDFs is depending on the shell you're running in that terminal expanding the wildcard, not Zip.  That expansion will not take place in your plist example.  @nohillside is correct.

Comment: @MarcWilson thanks for explaining. Didn’t realize that